# changing window size of Tkinter object with element.bind

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

When initialising tkinter gui element our gui is placed in specific window with its own title, icon and many other fun stuff.

I am creating some gui program that needs to implement console function with specific graphical interface. Program ordinary works with voice activated commands, so when user is mute/deaf by press of a button console will be implemented so user can communicate with program.

So console should be visible only when user press a key on keyboard, and by implementing console window size must change to compensate for console space since window is fixed size and not resizable.

So lets say we have some tkinter object:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals,with_statement

vStr = lambda x: type(x).__name__ in 'unicode,str'

try:
    from Tkinter import Tk
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk

class wind(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._ = Tk()
        self._.title('programm')
        self._.geometry('300x400+1+1')

        self._.bind('<space>', self.change_size)
        self.change = False

    def change_size(self,event):
        #some code here

    def init(self):
        self._.mainloop()

app = wind()
app.init()
```

How can i change size of an window `self._` root object on event.

Comment: you already seem to know how to set the size with `geometry` -- have you tried using that same method in `change_size`?

Comment: yap, i've succeeded it in answer :D It worked after several tries

Answer (score 0):

The function behind a **bind**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals,with_statement

vStr = lambda x: type(x).__name__ in 'unicode,str'

try:
    from Tkinter import Tk
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk

class wind(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._ = Tk()
        self._.title('programm')
        self._.geometry('300x400+1+1')

        self._.bind('<space>', self.change_size)
        self.change = False

    def change_size(self,event):
        if self.change:
            self._.geometry('200x500+3+3')
        else:
            self._.geometry('300x400+1+1')

        self.change = not self.change

    def init(self):
        self._.mainloop()

app = wind()
app.init()
```

Works on Windows on py2.7 and py3.5